# working map suddenly display crosses

Tags: android

I was during developing my map based android app, then after running it couple of times in emulator, suddenly map gone and shows crosses. I had obtained a new key yesterday.

I'm using android 2.2 V8.
thanks all.

Comment: did you mean that you tested on the emulator and works fine but not in the real device?

Comment: no no , all on emulator. it was working then suddenly shows crosses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you signin and exporting the application with the debug.keystore? if so, the app will not shows you the MapView. 
You have to create a sdk fingerprint (with the sdk that are you using) and generate the apy key for that one, and using into the MapView, did you make this?

to generate a new sdk fingerprint do in a shell;

```
keytool -genkey -alias anAlias -keystore myStore
```

write a password and complete all information requested;

when you´re finished do this to obtain the MD5 fingerprint:

```
keytool -list -keystore myStore
```

then, register that fingerprint with google maps api signup, put the generated key into the MapView layout. Now use this keystore to sign and export your application, if all is good the MapView will show on "non-debuggable" environments, i mean, when you distributes your app.

hope this help
cheers

Comment: hey thanks for answer friend. what I did was exporting "signed application package" , then get the MD5 from new x.keystore and then obtained a key. The part you mentioned (create sdk fingerprint) no I didnt do that , I dont know how to do that. would you plz explain?

Comment: all right, i always use the same keystore and the same alias to export "signed application package". Not creating new keystore every time :)

Comment: friends I have working map right now, but sometimes it doenst work, shows only crosses. I have fingerprint/appKey. I can tell more, when I try to send geoPoints from DDMS map suddenly displays crosses!!! Any IDEAS?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting blank map or sometimes crosses because points used to send by DDMS was not correct.
Send correct formated lat and lng like (+/-) xx.xxxxxx